# How to load 10k above charecter to single oracle coulmmn using sql loader

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I am spooling data from cassandra as file.
Column is

```
Id | text_file
---------------
1   JSON string (13000 characters string)
```

i have to load this data to oracle table.
what should be my oracle table structure and ctl file format.

Comment: Ideally a `CLOB` for text_file column. But, your question looks too broad. Restrict it to specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SQL Loader** for it. I am assuming that your file contains two fields. One is `Id` and other is `text_file` and you want to load it in

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '<filepath>'
TRUNCATE -- see oracle docs for more options here
INTO TABLE <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>
fields terminated by '|'
(
  ID,
  text_file CHAR(13000) -- Size needs to be mentioned here if it is more than 255 characters
)
```

> By default, the buffer for SQL loader is 255 characters but you can
>   alter it using CHAR(n) as mentioned in the example.

Then execute this control file using

```
sqlldr control=<aforementioned_file_path>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: value used for ROWS parameter changed from 64 to 16
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table table_name.
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'DBA_TS'

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table table_name.
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'DBA_TS'